# Headless SDL event handling

Tags: rust, sdl, sdl-2

Is it possible to listen for events in system using SDL without creating a window?
I want my app to listen on events in a system, and when certain shortcuts are pressed, I'll create a window with actual UI.

```
extern crate sdl2;

fn main() {
    let ctx = sdl2::init().unwrap();

    let mut event_pump = ctx.event_pump().unwrap();

    event_pump.pump_events();

    for event in event_pump.wait_iter() {
        match event {
            _ => { print!("event") }
        }
    }
}
```

If this is not possible, is there a cross-platform way to listen for global shortcuts or I have to re-implement it for every platform myself?

Comment: Why the sdl-2 requirement? Also it appears that what you want to build could be misused as a key logger.

Comment: I'd be glad to use anything to subscribe to system-wide shortcut events, if that would be more secure. I also chrose sdl2 because it is obviouly newer , but if there is a way to do what I want with sdl1 I'd be happy to switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar situation (the need to pump/process events without creating a window) and from what I have understood from studying SDL2 sources it is currently impossible to pump events without video system being initialized (at least in version 2.0.4).

Please see http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/e12c38730512/src/events/SDL_events.c (I used SDL 2.0.4), function **SDL_PumpEvents**, lines 397-402. That code checks whether video system was initialized and if it was calls **PumpEvents** method for that window system (I suppose it calls appropriate implementation for X11/Wayland/etc).

Comment: And even if I'll create video subsystem, I would only be able to listen for events that belong to the associated window, right?

Comment: @YurySolovyov I can not tell right now because it requires more thorough studying of SDL sources.